# When dismiss the Popover, How to save the current state?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, popover

By Storyboard segue, I made a Popover View. In the popover viewcontroller, there are two SWITCH (On/OFF). Everything is OK. But after dismiss the the popover viewcontroller, when re-call the popover view, The Popover's state is the default. That is, SWITCH is ON everytime. How to save the changed state(SWITCH is OFF, If done).

This is may code for PopOver

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "noticePopover" {
        let popoverViewController = segue.destination
        popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.view.alpha = 0.5
        })

        segue.destination.popoverPresentationController?.backgroundColor = inspotPointColor
    }
}

func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.none
}
func popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) {
    print("popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover")
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        self.view.alpha = 1.0
    })
}
```

I have searched this issue but I could not find the solution. Please inform me as your kindness.

Comment: You need to save the switch state somewhere; UserDefaults, Core Data, a plist file, or even just hold it in a variable somewhere. Then you can set the switch state in `viewDidLoad` for your popover view controller

Comment: Thanks your comment. I see the road for solving it. I try to coding UserDefaults.

Comment: PaulW11? As your comment, I succeed it only SWITCH. But Popover view is the state of notification(PUSH). That is the state of Setting > notification on/off. Could I save the total state of ViewController?

Comment: @Bennie, saving the data locally will be a fix for your problem as Paulw has already said, What be the relevant logic is up to you. Do your logic according to your requirements?

Comment: @Basir Alam. Thank for your comment. The main reason would be my confusing logic.I will check my logic and rebuild it. ^^

Comment: @Bennie Kim. Sure, please try and please let us know.

Comment: @Basir Alam. I checked my logic and user scenario, then made the simple logic. So, This problem was solved. My consideration was TOO detail!. Thank you for me to go to the BASIC.

Comment: @Bennie Kim, you welcome bro.